# ¿Cómo devuelvo un valor o un string recursivamente en javascript sin detener la función? (no quiero imprimir por consola)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Tengo esta función, **le pasas un array de strings e *imprime* (o más bien debería devolver) el string poco a poco, letra por letra** como si se estuviera escribiendo, eso quiero pasarlo a un componente de *React* para así que parezca que las palabras se escriben solas una y otra vez, **pero no sé cómo regresar el valor sin detener la función,** lo único que puedo hacer es imprimirla por consola y eso no me sirve.

```
export default function TypeWriter(words = [""]) {
  let texts = words;
  let count = 0;
  let index = 0;
  let currentText = "";
  let letter = "";

  function type() {
    if (count === texts.length) {
      count = 0;
    }
    currentText = texts[count];
    letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index);
    console.log(letter);
    if (letter.length === texts[count].length) {
      count++;
      index = 0;
      setTimeout(type, 3000);
    } else {
      setTimeout(type, 500);
    }
  }
  type();
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. Español, ¿Cuál es el comportamiento de la función `TypeWriter` en este momento? ¿Se detiene al terminar de recorrer el array de strings?. Y el objetivo es que **se vea una palabra tras otra sin detener el ciclo**.

Comment: En el comentario de arriba más bien, **el objetivo es que se vea una letra tras otra y una vez que la palabra se a terminado de escribir, re iniciar el ciclo `typeWriter`**, por favor avísanos si es el el objetivo.

Comment: Es imposible que la funcion te retorne mas de 1 vez letra por letra, lo que puedes hacer es como estas trabajando con react utiliza un hook como `useState` en vez del console log y react te deberia renderear el texto por cada iteracion, o tambien utilizar en vez del console log un `document.querySelector()` si lo quires hacer con javascript vanilla

Comment: Yo utilizaría una callback, le pasas aparte de `words` una función a la que llamas en vez del `console.log`, y que la vista se encargue de pintarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo resolvi, mi plan era que me devolviera constantemente un string para asi pasarlo a react como si fuera una simple variable pero mejor le agrege un parametro "query" a mi funcion, recibe un classname y asi puedo reutilizar la misma funcion una y otra vez simplemente ejectuto la funcion en un `useEffect` en react y  :)
asi quedo

```
    export default function TypeWriter({
      words = [""],// las palabras
      SpeedSchrtr = 300, //velocidad entre caracteres
      SpeedWord = 3000,//velocidad para cambiar de palabra
      stop = false, //solo poner la primera palabra
      query = false, //cual es el query o el classname
    }) {
      let texts = words;
      let count = 0; //indice en el array
      let index = 0; //indice en la palabra
      let currentText = ""; //que palabra se esta typewriteando
      let letter = ""; //resultado en el momento
      type();
      function type() {
        //this function will be ejected the whole time
        if (count === texts.length) {
          count = 0;
        }
        currentText = texts[count];
        letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index);
        //this only will work if you've pass an query on the parameters

        if (query ) {
          document.querySelector(query).textContent = letter;
        }
        //recursividad
        if (letter.length === texts[count].length && stop === false) {
          //si termino con la palbra actual...
          count++; // reinicia el contador de palabras
          index = 0;
          setTimeout(type, SpeedWord); //y vuelve a empezar con un pequeño delay
          // y reincicia el contador de letras
        } else {
          //si no ha terminado con la palabra simplemente vuelve a empezar :)
          setTimeout(type, SpeedSchrtr);
        }
      }
    }
```

al final solo pasas la funcion en react asi:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    TypeWriter({
      words: ["hola mundo", "estas palabras", "se escribiran", "infinitamente", "en un loop"],
      SpeedSchrtr: 100,
      SpeedWord: 4000,
      query: ".header--b",
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes solucionar tu problema con [generadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

```js
function* typeGenerator(words = ['']) {
    let currentIndex = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (currentIndex >= words.length) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }

        const currentText = words.slice(0, currentIndex).join('') || '';
        const newLetter = words[currentIndex++] || '';

        const reset = yield {
            currentText,
            newLetter
        };

        if (reset) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

const type = typeGenerator('hola mundo'.split(''));
const currentTextElement = document.querySelector('#current-text');
const newLetterElement = document.querySelector('#new-letter');

setInterval(() => {
    write(type.next().value);
}, 1200);

function write({ currentText, newLetter }) {
    currentTextElement.innerHTML = currentText;
    newLetterElement.classList.add('animate');
    newLetterElement.innerHTML = newLetter;
    setTimeout(() => {
        newLetterElement.classList.remove('animate');
    }, 500)
}
```

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: pre;
}

span#new-letter {
    margin-left: -4px;
}

span#new-letter.animate {
    animation: fadeInDown 0.3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Type writer</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <span id="current-text"></span>
        <span id="new-letter"></span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```